# Two Ionic apps on iPhone appearing to open each other

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I have two completely different Ionic apps running on my iPhone and I can get one to open the other and visa versa!

First app, App-V3, is an Ionic V3 app that has been in production for years and has been downloaded for App Store. Second app, App-V4, is an Ionic V4 app that is still in development and loaded onto my phone with Xcode. The code bases are completely different as are the back-ends and remote databases.

Procedure: both apps have been stopped, i.e. will restart, display launch image, to open.

1. Either app - start, wait for launch image to come and go, and then the app becomes live.
2. Close this app using home button on my iPhone6S.
3. Then immediately open the other app.
   The correct launch image displays but the original app appears!! The order makes no difference, start with App-V3 or App-V4, will have that app running in the other with above steps.

This does seem to be time dependent. After opening one app, after that app becomes live, if I wait for approximately 6 seconds or more, then close it, and immediately open the other app, then this app will start correctly. It seems that if I wait for only 5 seconds or less, then I will see the issue.

I would like to understand why this is happening. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have the same Id in the config.xml of your both projects, I know in android wont let you install it if its the same.

Comment: Thanks but no, these are different. BTW - this issue does not appear on my Android.